# Change system time using JNA java SetSystemTime

Tags: java, date, time, jna

In Java, we are getting the system time by calling `System.currentTimeMillis()` which returns long value. We are having server and clients in local network and to keep them synchronized, we need to ensure that computers have the same time. (+/- 10 seconds tolerable)

We need to change the system time of the client computers using java. We tried to use the command prompt `date -s` but it requires administrator rights. So it did not work. We then tried to make native call to `SetSystemTime` in `kernel32` library using `Function function = Function.getFunction("kernel32", "SetSystemTime");` but somehow we could not manage to make it work.

Currently, this is how we attempt to run this native call.

```
Function function = Function.getFunction("kernel32", "SetSystemTime");
    Object [] params = new Object [] {
        "2015",
        "4",
        "0",
        "13",
        "14",
        "28",
        "0",
        "0"
    };

    System.out.println("invoking...");
    boolean result = (Boolean)function.invoke(Boolean.class, params);
    System.out.println(result);
```

And we are getting `false` as result. Using JNA library.
Our purpose is to modify the value returned by `System.currentTimeMillis()`. There are some 3rd party libraries we are using which uses `System.currentTimeMillis()` so we cannot use/create another call.

If anyone has a better idea than using JNA, please do advice. Actually, we do not find it efficient to import the JNA library just to change the system date/time but that is what we have right now.

Comment: Configure NTP servers for both machines, then the time should be really close to identical

Comment: As @Yuri suggested configure NTP for your network and machines. Also `date -s` requires admin privileges because `SetSystemTime` is a priviledged call. So calling `SetSystemTime` will require admin privilege or a certain permission. Check `SetSystemTime` documentation.

Comment: @Yuri Some suggested the same thing but we would prefer doing this in code if possible as we have many computers in local network and many local networks in remote places. Any ideas?

Comment: Well, it is kind of what the Network Time Protocol is aimed at... Maybe access an NTP server via Java? http://support.ntp.org/bin/view/Support/JavaSntpClient

Comment: As others have said, priveleged permissions are required.  Can you run your Java program as an administrator?   If so, you might just want to do that and it will have the permissions to make the `date` and `time` commandline calls.